# How do i find this angle in a right triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

So I'm writing a program and I need to write a method that will give me the angle of a specific angle of a triangle when I know only the adjacent length and opposite length.
I know that $\tan(A) = \frac{\text{opposite side}}{\text{adjacent side}}$ but how would I solve for $A$ in that equation?

Comment: Have you heard of inverse trigonometric functions. See here... en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions

Comment: Never have been taught that in school, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In terms of software, you have two options: you can search for a trig library that will make inverse tan available as a function/method or you can construct a look-up table. A look up table could be a two-dimensional array with angles from 0 to 180 in one column and corresponding inverse tan values in the other column.

Comment: A look-up table will be cumbersome if the input angles are allowed to be non-integers.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, [as George Watts said](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/98866/72), you're looking for the inverse tangent function.  Depending on what programming language, that's probably a function called `atan` or `arctan` or some variant of that.

As you said you're working in a right triangle, the angle you're looking for is $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ (it's most likely that the function in your programming language will give an answer in radians, not in degrees) and $$\tan\theta=\frac{\text{opposite leg}}{\text{adjacent leg}}\;\;\Leftrightarrow\;\;\theta=\arctan\left(\frac{\text{opposite leg}}{\text{adjacent leg}}\right).$$

Note that if you're not exactly trying to find an acute angle in a right triangle (e.g. if you're trying to find the angle of inclination of a line), you might be better off with the 2-argument arctan function (often `atan2`) or some other technique.